# Data not collected correctly from JSON object using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I'm trying to create a function that selects data from database in server-side and sets it as value of textbox in client-side. It works fine in server-side, but in client side, if I write a console.log for the data, it shows `undefined` and I can't figure out why. Thanks a lot !

**Server-side:**

```
app.post('/id', function(req,res) {

    var data = req.body;
    var id = data.id;
    console.log(id);
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Control WHERE id=" +id;
    connection.query(query, function(error, result) {
            console.log(result);
            res.json(result);
    });
});
```

**Client-side:**

```
function select()
            {
                var id = $('#nr_reg').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/id',
                    data : {
                        id: id
                    },
                    success : function(data){           
                        console.log(data);                          
                        var id = data.id;
                        $('#optic').val(id);

                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                }); 
            }
```

**The result from server after the query:**

```
5 //this is the id which is correct
[ { id: 5,
    data: '',
    kw: '6',
    nr_articol: '279630-99',
    proiect: 'AUHE',
    optic: '0',
    electric: '',
    reelectric: '',
    smd: 'on',
    scurt_smd: '0',
    incomplete_smd: '',
    bile: '',
    val: '',
    scurt_val: '',
    incomplete_val: '',
    nivel_cositor: '',
    greseli_smd: '',
    lipsa_smd: '',
    invers_smd: '',
    plantare_manuala: '',
    componente_lipsa: '',
    componente_inversate_1: '',
    greseli_hotbar: '',
    lipire_hotbar: '',
    greseli_asamblare: '',
    componente_inversate_2: '',
    greseli_imprimare: '',
    componente_inversate_3: '',
    greseli_aspect: '',
    fire_lovite: '',
    componente_inversate_4: '',
    casaste: '',
    reparate: '',
    Total: '0' } ]
```

Comment: what does the serverside object look like and what about the client object you are receiving? and what do you expect it to look like?

Comment: you have two data options in the jquery ajax call. data: JSON.stringify(data) and data: {id: id}

Comment: looks abit like a mixed post/get request..

Comment: I have updated the first post to see how the console shows the result after the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try use `data[0]`

Since your outcome is: `[{ id: 5,.... }]` it means a object in an array.
in order to data.id work, your outcome should be `{id: 5,.....}`. So try this:

```
            function select()
            {
                var id = $('#nr_reg').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/id',
                    data : {
                        id: id
                    },
                    success : function(data){           
                        console.log(data);                          
                        var id = data[0].id;
                        $('#optic').val(id);

                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                }); 
            }
```

Comment: you are welcome! the [] means it is in an array, that is why i guessed the data[0]